# Inherit from existing style and add new shapes to derived style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, expression-blend, blend

I have basic style `PlayButtonsStyle` and `PauseButtonStyleInherited` that is based on the first one. How can I add shapes to the derived one? I want to add two rectangles so it looks like pause button (Blend or VS)

derived:

```
<Style x:Key="PauseButtonStyleInherited" BasedOn="{StaticResource PlayButtonsStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
```

basic:

```
<Style x:Key="PlayButtonsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse1">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse2">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="180"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="glow">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="glow">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="glow">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="glow">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.784"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.784"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-4.231"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="4.292"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="isPressed"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="0.068,0.333,-0.264,0.666" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse2" Margin="-0.106,0.018,0.106,-0.018" Stroke="#FF555453" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.426269" RadiusY="0.426269" Center="0.488153,0.0751377" GradientOrigin="0.488153,0.0751377">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDCD7D3" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFBDB9B5" Offset="0.576744"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF9E9B98" Offset="0.767442"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4B4A49" Offset="1"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Margin="1.796,2.097,2.008,2.061" Width="Auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
                        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF898989" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF727272" Offset="0.132447"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5C5C5C" Offset="0.32093"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF060606" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>

                    <Ellipse x:Name="glow" Margin="1.831,2.138,2.045,2.102" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.412293" RadiusY="0.41654" Center="0.300546,0.229947" GradientOrigin="0.300546,0.229947">
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <SkewTransform CenterX="0.300546" CenterY="0.229947" AngleX="-1.08514" AngleY="0"/>
                                        <RotateTransform CenterX="0.300546" CenterY="0.229947" Angle="238.875"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Color="#A4FFFAFF" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#52FFFCFF" Offset="0.40678"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse1" Height="8.982" Margin="-7.773,0,-5.394,-9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0" d:IsHidden="True">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5F5F5F" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#7F2F2F38" Offset="0.605"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#4C141418" Offset="0.824"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>                      
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsCancel" Value="False"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="isPressed_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="isPressed_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource isPressed}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that.  I think you'll need to redefine the control template with the additional shapes in the derived style.